# How to invoke a dialog from a menu?

Tags: python, interface

More specifically - how to invoke a `invoke_props_dialog` from a `bpy.types.Menu`?

The dialog invokes properly from Search, but not from a menu.

This is an operator that invokes a dialog:

```
import bpy

class MyDialog(bpy.types.Operator):

    bl_idname = "tools.mydialog"
    bl_label = "My Dialog"

    string_prop = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="String Prop")

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)

    def execute(self, context):

        return {'FINISHED'}

bpy.utils.register_class(MyDialog)
```

Comment: It works from search as well as from menu, not sure what you mean? If it doesn't, the operation context might be changed in the particular menu you add the operator to. If so, create a layout subelement (row, column, split...) and set `sub.operation_context = 'INVOKE_DEFAULT'` above `sub.operator(...)`. http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=operator_context#bpy.types.UILayout.operator_context

Answer (score 2):

What about doing it like this ?

```
import bpy

class MyDialog(bpy.types.Operator):

    bl_idname = "tools.mydialog"
    bl_label = "My Dialog"

    string_prop = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="String Prop")

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)

    def execute(self, context):
        # Whatsoever needs to be done...
        return {'FINISHED'}

def my_menu_addition(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(MyDialog.bl_idname)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    bpy.utils.register_class(MyDialog)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file.append(my_menu_addition)
```

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51135822/blender-python-add-operator-to-menu-with-invoke-default here is the answer

```
layout.operator_context = "INVOKE_DEFAULT"
```

Comment: this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an operator which uses calls `invoke_props_dialog` from its invoke function. Then reference this operator from your menu.

Comment: An operator like http://www.pasteall.org/53035/python ? That works from Search, but doesn't from a menu.

Comment: please include sample code in question, better then referencing external sites which may become dead links.

Comment: Done.----------